# Why does laravel say that the file not exist when uploading with tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),'')

Tags: php, laravel, file, download, tmp

I am using laravel with my project. 
I try to put the generated file in the tmp folder before it gets downloaded. Somehow it says that the file is not in the tmp folder. So I think I am not putting the file in this folder. That is only because it gives me the error that **file doesn't exist** in this folder.

You can see in the code below that I make a variable which gets me the tempname of the folder I will put it in:

```
$foldedFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),'/pdf');
```

After that I have a little bit of code. Which provides the file with the content it needs and with paper size it will be, after that i save the file in the **$foldedFile** folder:

```
\PDF::loadHTML($content)
      ->setPaper('a4')
      ->save($foldedFile, true);
```

After that I return everything in the response and download the file, which has the right `$project->name`:

```
return Response::download($foldedFile."/".$project->name . ".pdf");
```

I fixed this problem with deleting the **$project->name**. I did indeed not pass the name of the project with the folder so it couldn't be found.

Comment: _“download the file, which has the right $project->name”_ - where from? You did not pass any project name when you created the temp file?

Comment: I didn't pass the name of the project so I deleted this one.